# Rails testing actions that require login (using cookies)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller whose index action is password protected:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  before_action :signed_in_user

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

I'm have a test:

```
test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:users)
end
```

The test fails because the user is redirected to the signin page when it is run:

```
def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?      
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end

def signed_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user=(user)
  @current_user = user
end

def sign_in(user)
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  self.current_user = user
end

def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

I know that I can use capybara to visit the signin page and log the test user in, but in my experience this usually leads to test suites that take ages to run, so I was hoping there might be a quick and dirty way to do this using sessions:

```
test "should get index" do
  get :index, { }, { remember_token: users(:one).remember_token }
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:users)
end

# I also tried the following:
test "should get index" do
  get :index, { }, { current_user: users(:one) }
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:users)
end
```

I was hoping that the above would magically log my test user in, but no, and we are still redirected to the signin page with a failing test.

What is the correct way to do this sort of thing? It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577167/how-to-test-cookies-state-in-functional-tests-in-rails). All I needed was:

```
setup do
  @user = users(:one)
  # since I am using cookies, I just need to set them here
  @request.cookies['remember_token'] = @user.remember_token
end

# no need to pass anything to the get method
test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:users)
end
```